# corona sdk iphone 4s 5.1.1 no sound

Tags: iphone, coronasdk

I don't have sound in apps on iphone 4s 5.1.1

tested my app + 2 (unmodified)examples from sample code

even when i send notifications - i get vibration (if with sound) - without sound i don't get vibration but in both cases sound does not play. not it notification not in app

Help!

I tried using ggmusic and ggsound libs by Glitched Games. Both of witch implement the new audio api.

here is some code so i meet the QUALITY STANDARTS

local supportedAudio = {
    ["Simulator"] = { extensions = { ".aac", ".aif", ".caf", ".wav", ".mp3", ".ogg" } },
    ["IOS"] = { extensions = { ".aac", ".aif", ".caf", ".wav", ".mp3" } },
    ["Android"] = { extensions = { ".wav", ".mp3", ".ogg" } },
}

Answer (score 1):

Ok guyz, the thing is - you should check that switch on the right side that turns off sounds. Your media playback will play via loudspeker, but sounds dont. Turn sounds on and it fixes it. 
Lame apple user I am.

Cheers!